# Can we differentiate $x^y =-1$ ? Why?

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Suppose $x^y =4$. I find $y'$ as follows:$$
y\ln x = \ln 4\\
y'\ln x + \frac{y}{x} = 0\\
y' = -\frac{y}{x\ln x} \cdot
$$

I am wondering how to find $y'$ when $x^y =-1$. Could you give some general rules/theorems?

Comment: To start, is $x^y=-1$ well defined? Take $x=-1$ And you'll find $y$ can be any odd integer.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $x^y=e^{y \ln x}>0$ !

Answer (score 0):

Negative numbers power to irrational (or some rationals) exponent is not define in  real numbers. Ex (-1)^(0.5)
Expression like x^y make sense only if x>0, and in this case there are no points (x,y) | x^y = -1.

Answer (score 0):

The relation $y\log x =\log 4$ reveals that
$$y' = -\frac{y}{x\log x} = -\frac{\log 4 / \log x}{x\log x} = -\frac{\log 4}{x\log^2 x}$$
which is what to expect since $y(x) = \log 4 /\log x$. Youtuber 3Blue1Brown has a nice [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qb40J4N1fa4) covering the intuition behind this.